# How to understand why time issue exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-application-insights

I look at the Application Insights log and see about page:

[image]

so, what I see... Page is loading 36 seconds, connect to db gets 7 ms. Action of controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BreadCrumb.Clear();
        BreadCrumb.Add(Url.Action("Index", "Home"), "Home");
        BreadCrumb.Add(Url.Action("Index", "Customers"), "Customer List");

        CustomerIndexVM model = new CustomerIndexVM();
        var customers = db.Customers.Include(c=>c.CustomerGeofencings).Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyId);
        model.List = mapper.Map<List<CustomerElementVM>>(customers);
        return View(model);
    }
```

How to understand why page is loading so long?

Comment: Do you mean the query takes 7ms or just the connection?

Comment: not sure. What application insights means about it on screenshot?

Comment: The 7ms reported in Application Insights means the total time required (eg. the timer starts when you trigger your call to the db and ends when you get a response back). This is at least the case for automatically tracked dependencies, you can record these manually with your own semantics.

Comment: so, rest of my code in controller takes 36 s -7ms ?

Answer (score 1):

For web apps you can install Service Profiler which should give you exact timings what you code did: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there could be a myriad of reasons why you're seeing this slow time...I'll try to list a few that spring to mind. Hopefully it'll help you diagnose further.

**The Site:**

- is your site 'warmed up' or is that a time for a cold call to the site (i.e. the site has to fire up). Azure has an `Always On` setting on AppServices you can set so the site never goes 'cold'. Obviously this will affect the monthly price you pay.

**The Code:**

- What happens if you comment out the following 2 lines - do you see a dramatic speed increase?

`var customers = db.Customers.Include(c=>c.CustomerGeofencings).Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyId);
model.List = mapper.Map<List<CustomerElementVM>>(customers);`

- if you do see a speed increase - could the database be a factor? - where is it located? (location doesn't seem like it would be an issue with a 7ms connection), Do you have indexes set up in your tables? Also, as a comparison try out `Dapper` if you haven't already - it is VERY fast: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Hope that takes you a step in the right direction.

Comment: site is `always on`

Comment: problem is the same page sometimes opened is very quickly. Sometimes takes 5+ seconds....

Comment: you could mark up the controller with some `StopWatch`s and you'll be able to see how long each element takes by pushing them as events to insights. I'm just wondering if it's EF being a bit lumbering at times